# Is there an efficient use for a surplus of Insects in Standard, Kaladesh to Ixalan?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Assuming the opponent has creatures in play, consider the following interaction:

[Hour of Devastation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHour%20of%20Devastation%5d) + [Soul-Scar Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul-Scar%20Mage%5d) + [Nest of Scarabs](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNest%20of%20Scarabs%5d)

This will generate 5 x (number of opponents creatures) insects.

Is there a card or set of cards that efficiently uses these insects to win the game? While it was previously directed to discard the damage done to your own creatures, an interaction that is reliant on a creature you control that would be killed by Hour of Devastation doesn't work; the creature is dead before the insects enter the battlefield.

Conditions and Limitations:
Standard Legal Cards, ranging from Kaladesh to Ixalan.
Supports a win either in the same turn or on the next one.
Understands that creatures in play will get 5 -1/-1 counters.

Comment: Are there any requirements on the cards, such as color or format?

Comment: You could simply attack for the win as long as your opponent had 5 or more creatures to start with...

Comment: This is still pretty open ended, as diego asked could you specify a format or color that you are looking for? As it is right now it is kind of hard to see what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: What does `Understands that creatures in play will get 5 -1/-1 counters.` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from simply attacking for the win on the following turn, you have many options:

- Grant them haste with [Samut, Voice of Dissent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSamut%2c%20Voice%20of%20Dissent%5d)
- Play a huge [Majestic Myriarch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMajestic%20Myriarch%5d) and [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFling%5d) him at your opponent

  - anothe option, without green: have both [Decoction Module](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDecoction%20Module%5d) and [Fabrication Module](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFabrication%20Module%5d) on the board when you cast the Hour, put all counters on one of the tokens and Fling that
- [Arcane Adaptation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcane%20Adaptation%5d) naming Zombie and drain opponent to death with [Plague Belcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlague%20Belcher%5d) and a sacrifice outlet (such as [Yahenni, Undying Partisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYahenni%2c%20Undying%20Partisan%5d))

  - You can also drain them with a [Wayward Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWayward%20Servant%5d) if you can make it survive the Hour (and can play white too)

There are probably many more, but these are the ones I came up with in a few minutes.

Comment: Epic Struggle comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

If just attacking won't work, [Throne of the God-Pharaoh](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThrone%20of%20the%20God-Pharaoh%5d) would damage your opponent for each surviving scarab.

In red, if your attack doesn't finish them off, [Makeshift Munitions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMakeshift%20Munitions%5d) will allow you to shoot your scarabs at your enemy.